# Azure DevOps API to check PAT expiry date

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-devops

I'm trying to check when a PAT token is expiring so I can create an alert/notification if a specific token is expiring soon and replace it before it expires.

There is an API to query all PAT within a organization:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Sadly this API requires write permissions on the org itself which I don't have. With the script below I get the following error:
`azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: Access Denied: XXX needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit instance-level information`

This brings me to my question:
Is there a way / an API to query my personal PATs without permissions on the org itself?

Here the current draft of the Python script to check the PAT for reference:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'XXX'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/XXX'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get personal subject_descriptor by mail
graph_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_graph_client()
user_descriptor = None
continuation_token = None

while True:
    graph_response = graph_client.list_users(continuation_token=continuation_token)
    continuation_token = graph_response.continuation_token
    for u in graph_response.graph_users:
        if u.mail_address == "my@mail":
            user_descriptor = u.descriptor
            break
    if continuation_token == None:
        break

# Get a client for token admin
token_admin_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_token_admin_client()

# Get list of personal access tokens
tokens_response = token_admin_client.list_personal_access_tokens(user_descriptor)

print(tokens_response)
```

Comment: Another idea, is to create two PAT tokens, with different expiration times. When the first expires, start using the other, and warn about how many days you have left. The idea is to have slightly different expiry days for the tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way / an API to query my personal PATs without permissions on the org itself?

Based on my test, this API indeed exists. This API doesn't exist in official documents.

We could get it in **Browser Console -> Network tab**.

[image: API]

Here is the template:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Org name/_apis/Token/SessionTokens?displayFilterOption=1&createdByOption=3&sortByOption=3&isSortAscending=true&startRowNumber=1&pageSize=100&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

This Rest API doesn't need to have the `Edit instance-level information`permission.

You just need to grant the **"Token Administration"** scope to the personal access token. Then you could run the API successfully.

[image: PAT Scope]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Lu, that is excatly what I was looking for! For reference here is a working implementation pushing the metrics to InfluxDB: https://gist.github.com/ydkn/e4ee3da80b2d9f8714faa395c9c554ed